# Unhandled exception at 0x003b1405 in COM.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000402

Tags: c++, com

I am trying to read the address of my PC's COM ports. I need to know which one is used and i guess this program should help me well. But it seems that i can't read from that address from memory, why?

```
void main(void)
{
 unsigned int *ptraddr =nullptr;  /* Pointer to location of Port Addresses */
 unsigned int address =0;       /* Address of Port */
 int a=0;

 ptraddr=(unsigned int*)0x00000402;

 for (a = 0; a <  4; a++)
   {
    address = *ptraddr;
    if (address == 0)
                printf("No port found for COM%d \n",a+1);
    else
                printf("Address assigned to COM%d is %Xh\n",a+1,address);
    *ptraddr++;
   }
}
```

Comment: On a protected system like "modern" Windows (well, Windows NT, which all modern Windows are based on, is 22 years old) you can't access any address you want. If you want to use COM ports in Windows you need to use the Windows API to get access to them,. Using direct addressing like that only worked in old unprotected DOS-based systems.

Comment: Ahaaaaaa, so that's the problem. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Joachim, it's been long time since you had the right to directly access peripherals like this. Please, have a look at this tutorial:

http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/i-n/network/serialcommunications/article.php/c2503/CSerial--A-C-Class-for-Serial-Communications.htm